# How can I view questions with 0 answers, that haven't been upvoted, and that are tagged with my favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, search

I believe this is impossible, currently, but I often find myself wanting to look at questions that abide a pretty specific set of criteria. It would be useful to have some kind of a tool that lets you search for those, similar to an SQL query.

Comment: would also probably check data explorer http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sathya That wouldn't be very helpful in this case. The data explorer is updated occasionally, not live. The last updates were in June, so anything he finds would most likely not fit the criteria anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following search term:

> [tag1] [tag2] answers:0

This will find all questions that have tags `[tag1]` and `[tag2]` and no answers

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks! Is there a way to include all of my favorite tags?

Comment: @bane - I don't think so

Comment: And what about logical operators? It appears that this searches for questions that have **both** tag1 and tag2, but sometimes I want questions that have either one of those...

Answer (score 2):

This will almost do the job:

```
[tag] answers:0 votes:0
```

However, the `votes:0` mean that it must have *at least* 0 votes and you will still see voted questions :(

However, a solution for this is to use that query and sort by **votes** and start searching from the last page.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Unanswered -> No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) tab for questions with no answers, *or* [Unanswered -> My tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) to get questions with no **upvoted answers** in your favourite tags, but I don't think there's a way to mix & match both.