# Is it possible to search for down voted questions?

Tags: support, search, down-votes

I want to search for new downvoted questions to improve or flag them.

I tried in the searchbar: `votes:-1 is:question`

but `votes:XX` only works with positive numbers. I can't query for downvoted questions. Is there a work-around to this? If there's not, should this feature be added?

Comment: something like this [should work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148844/179635), just sort by votes and start looking from the last page. **edit:** this will work when the search is less than `5,000` results

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find questions with very negative votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262307/how-to-find-questions-with-very-negative-votes)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: My Question is 2 years older and has a correct answer. so the new one you linked should be the duplicate.

Comment: The age is irrelevant and the other has better answers @sim.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I agree with you. Since the high-reps have marked that question as duplicate, I have posted my updated answer below specifically related to OP's question and his/her own accepted answer.

Comment: @ajax333221 please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature of searching withing a range of a score has been added. This feature contains also searching for questions with negative votes. use:

`score:..-1`

Have a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156466/190805).

Comment: searching with just "score:..-1" would result both i.e. questions and answers with negative votes. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

Now that the newly posted question [How to find questions with very negative votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262307/how-to-find-questions-with-very-negative-votes) has been marked as a duplicate of this question. I would like to post my updated answer for this question specifically addressing the following two questions asked by OP:

OP's question in the title says:

> Is it possible to search for down voted questions?

So, as per the question OP wants to find the *down voted **questions*** and the answer for that is to search it by entering either of the following two search options in the search box:

**score:..-1 is:question**

or

**votes:..-1 is:question**

The above search query will *only* display all the *questions* with *negative* votes. It's very important to include the **is:question** type option here otherwise *just* searching with "score:..-1" (as given in the OP's own accepted answer) would result *both* i.e. questions and answers with negative votes.

Here is a screenshot of result shown using *just* **score:..-1** (top section of the 1st page of the total 9,920 results shown)

> [image]

If you notice, the last two posts have "answered" in the status posted by user's BalusC and CanSpice respectively. If you click on them, you will see that it's the *answer* that got the negative vote here whereas the *question* has only *up-votes* (and no down-votes).

Here is the screenshot with a search query using **score:..-1 is:question** option: (notice 7,375 results as oppose to above 9,920 results)

> [image]

The above search results only displays all the questions with *negative* votes and have a question status of "***asked***". So, it is very *important* to include the **is:question** type option here.

Now, lets move to the next part of the question. In body of the question OP says: (emphasis mine)

> I want to search for **new** downvoted questions to improve or flag them.

For this, all you have to do is click on the "**newest**" search tab and search result will be sorted accordingly.

Comment: This should be part of the advanced searching tips.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like searching for `votes:-1 is:question` does yield questions with at least negative one votes (when ordered by Relevance, the last few pages are all questions with scores of -1, though when they're ordered by votes, the last pages all have scores of 13 for me, which makes it look as though it is not working; it looks like only the first 5000 results or so in the selected order are taken, so the last page will be positively voted questions, since there are more than 5000 of them without further specification) The Search Tips say of the `votes` option:

> posts with a minimum number of votes   votes:15 apples oranges

so it looks like there is not currently a way to search for only downvoted questions, since any negative search will include upvoted questions as well, but you can use negative values.