# Search keyword "votes" not documented?

Tags: support, search

I recently try to search for questions with upvotes and I forgot the search syntax and just guessed the keywords.
My query in the search box was something similar like this:

```
[cxf] answers:0 votes:3
```

It found 15 questions.

After this I opened the "Advanced Search Tips" and saw there is no "votes" keyword, but there is "score".

However they seem to have the same meaning because if I search:

```
[cxf] answers:0 score:3
```

It found the same 15 results.

Is this an official synonym? Or one is deprecated and will be decommissionned soon?

Comment: Votes is the incorrect word by all means as a score is determined by up votes -/- down votes. What ever the answer is, votes shouldn't be a search option.

Comment: Hmm, [score and votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162063/158100) are synonyms. But I think they really shouldn't be because they are not...

Comment: Ok, I see why votes is used to indicate score because if you look at the post list the number is labeled votes, not score...

Comment: @rene that's true, and there's a long time [feature request asking to change that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153515/use-score-instead-of-votes-in-the-list-of-questions)...

Comment: I barked at Nick for calling those synonyms. I removed my comment there, let's hope he doesn't find out it was me...

Comment: What makes me think it is votes, is that in [this page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions) (biology.SE as an example) the tabs are named `newest`, `featured`, `frequent` and `votes` finally in the UI it should also be named `score` in sake of consistency.